# React JS map cards images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While im getting imgs list from API by custom hook show loader component, then map list. Problem - card item images shows not the same time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNTKq.jpg)

Custom hook :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useFetch(typeTabByPopular, tabListType) {
  const [list, setList] = useState("");
  const [page, setPage] = useState("1");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/${tabListType}/
      ${typeTabByPopular}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&&page=${page}`,
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setList(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [tabListType, typeTabByPopular, page]);
  return { list, setPage, loading };
}
```

Comment: images are loading so you need to wait for it else make skeleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All image elements have an onLoad event you can use to benefit this aim.

Since you have a list of images, then you know how many images should be on each page.
Put a counter of `loadedImages` and on the onLoad of each image using `setLoadedImages` to raise it by 1.

Until the counter is equal to the number of images on the page render a loader and when it matches the number of images render the images.